# Read and send multiple lines instead of one

Tags: python, python-3.x, arduino

I'm having an Arduino setup with a mini displayed. It's programmed so whatever I type into the serial "command line" will be printed to the display.

**Foods.txt:**

```
First Line
```

This works fine if the txt file only has one Line

```py
import serial
import tim

f = open("Foods.txt", "r")
lines = f.readline()

for line in lines:
    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART", 115200, timeout=1)
    commandToSend = lines
    ser.write(str(commandToSend).encode())
```

Output is this this:

```
First Line
```

If I add lines to "Foods.txt":

```
First Line
Second Line
Third Line
Fourth Line
```

I get this output (first line 11 times):

```
First Line
First Line
First Line
First Line
First Line
First Line
First Line
First Line
First Line
First Line
First Line
```

If I change `f.readlines()` to lines instead of line in order to read multiple lines one by one, it also kind of works but I got the problem that it will not add the carriage return to each line (\r) so after using the script nothing happens

```py
import serial
import time


f = open("Foods.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:

    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART", 115200, timeout=1)
    commandToSend = lines
    ser.write(str(commandToSend).encode())
```

So I Screen into the device and press ender and I get

```
["first Line\n", "Second Line\n". "Third Line\n","Fourth Line\n"]
["first Line\n", "Second Line\n". "Third Line\n","Fourth Line\n"]
["first Line\n", "Second Line\n". "Third Line\n","Fourth Line\n"].   
["first Line\n", "Second Line\n". "Third Line\n","Fourth Line\n"]
```

Which means that it send them to the serial console but it didn't press "enter" to send them and as soon as I ran the first script it pressed enter for all of it.

How do I add \r to it?

If I do it like this:

```py
import serial
import time


f = open("Foods.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:

    ser = serial.Serial("/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART", 115200, timeout=1)
    commandToSend = lines\r
    ser.write(str(commandToSend).encode())
```

I get

```
    commandToSend = lines\r
                          ^
    SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second approach looks right to me, the problem is that you are setting `commandToSend` to `lines`, which is a list of all the lines, what you want to send instead is `line` (the current line in the list you are looping on).

So your code should be:

```py
import serial
import time

f = open("Foods.txt", "r")
lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:
    ser = serial.Serial('/dev/cu.SLAB_USBtoUART', 115200, timeout = 1)
    commandToSend = line
    ser.write(str(commandToSend).encode()).
```

Also, if you wanted to add a carriage return, you would have to concatenate it as a string, eg:

```py
line + '\r'
```

or

```py
'%s\r' % line
```

or

```py
'{}\r'.format(line)
```

or

```py
f'{line}\r'
```

Depending on preferences / Python version